# BigQuery - cannot UNION String and NULL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables that I am trying to `UNION`. Column `id` in `table1` is of type `STRING`. I do not have that column in `table2` so I am writing `SELECT NULL AS id FROM table2` but BigQuery thinks that column `id` in `table2` is of type `INT64`.

I get this error -
`Column 2 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: STRING, INT64`.

Query works if I write `SELECT "" AS id FROM table2` instead.

Comment: In your upper query select `cast(null as string)`

Comment: ..or `STRING(NULL)` should work as well

Answer (score 7):

SELECT id FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(NULL AS STRING) FROM table2